# Refresh WPF Grid layout upon removing elements at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, dynamic-resizing

I have a wpf application in which I am using a wpf grid and adding/removing controls dynamically to it. Adding controls is fine but upon removing they disappear from the grid but left the vacant place in them, which I want to be occupied by filled by rest of the elements, just like they did in wrap panel.

Previously I was using the wrap panel and it works fine, but I need to add splitter control among my groupboxes thus I replaced the wrappanel with grid.

Here are the screenshots of the window

[image]

I remove the middle groupbox and it displays like this

[image]

I want the third groupbox to occupy the place of second groupbox.
For the record, I have used grid resize event and this is the code it is having

```
 foreach (var control in this.DynamicGrid.Children)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
            {
                GroupBox groupBox = control as GroupBox;
                groupBox.Height = this.DynamicGrid.ActualHeight;
                this.WrapPanel1.Width = this.DynamicGrid.ActualWidth;
            }
        }
```

Wrappanel has dynamic grid in which we are adding/removing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your 
`<ColumnDefinition width="Auto" />`

and use
`Visibility="Collapsed"` to hide the column.

Comment: ColumnDefinition width="Auto" solves the problem for me.

Comment: Fine :) just be careful, you can still focus the hidden control using tab. If you have some keyboard actions you should do something to prevent it.

Comment: Elements get aligned if I use Column definition="Auto" but grid is not resizing itself. it should decrease its width as well.

Comment: <Grid with="auto" > didn't do anything ?

Comment: for the record, I am using grid sizechanged event. I have added the code of that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see your problem... it seems as though you are asking 'How do I use a `Grid` control in code?'. If you want to alter the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` (or any other `Grid` property) at runtime, then why not do just that? If you look at the [`Grid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see a long code example where it shows you exactly how to manipulate a `Grid` in code. For example, you could do something like this:

```
ColumnDefinition rightHandColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
YourGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(rightHandColumn);
YourGrid.Children.Add(uiElementCurrentlyInGrid);
YourGrid.SetRow(uiElementCurrentlyInGrid, 0);
YourGrid.SetColumn(uiElementCurrentlyInGrid, 1);
```

Then to remove an item:

```
Grid.Children.Remove(uiElementCurrentlyInGrid);
Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Remove(rightHandColumn);
```